# To create dual window application

Tags: wpf

first window and second window will have same control like textbox or button
once some entry happend in first window it should reflect in second window also and vice-versa and in case of event also.
you can say first is mirror of second window vice-versa so any one, so can any one tell me how should i start for this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mvvm  - create 1 viewmodel where you hold your data and bind the same instance of this viewmodel to both windows/views as the datacontext, create your bindings twoway and all works like you want.

btw i really dont know what you wanna do with your app :)

Comment: Yeah seriously, is this the main window or just controls? What is your intention? Ever look at Unity?

Comment: thanks for your replay. i know, binding can handle this with updatesourcetrigger or by referring the controls like this way <TextBox Name="txt of firstwindow" Text='{Binding ElementName=txt of second window,Path="Text",Mode="TwoWay"}' ></TextBox> & <TextBox Name='txt of second window' Text="{Binding ElementName=txt of firstwindow,Path=Text,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
 but how i raise button or label etc. events in both window when event raise in single window. it means both window have same page with same button and at time click happens only single window and should reflect to both window.